# python3 in json have as value a variable

Tags: python, json

I would like to achieve something that seems very easy but I cannot since I am new to python. I have seen a lot of posts in the web but are not easily understandable.

How can I set a value of a json as a variable?
For example below:

```
import requests 
from getmac import get_mac_address
              eth_mac = get_mac_address()
              newHeaders = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
             response = requests.post('.......device.php',
                                 data={"mascineid": 1, "mac":eth_mac},
                                      headers=newHeaders)
          print(response.json())
```

how can I write the code near 'eth_mac' text so I can type there a variable?

By the above code I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pythoniot.py", line 83, in <module>
    print(response.json())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 518, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean? `eth_mac` ***is*** a variable.

Comment: eth_mac is the variable name. it is not the correct way to type a variable as a python code

Comment: I'm not following. What is the "correct way to type a variable as a python code" that you're talking about? Or, to frame it another way, what are you trying to do with this code, and what's happening instead? See [mre].

Comment: I am trying to post the mac address value of the specified device. So each time the post runs it will post the value of the variable. I try to write it as I think of it. the code is not working but I need to have a variable at 'eth_mac'. For example in java it would be: "data={'mascineid': 1, 'mac': "+eth_mac+"},"

Comment: Again, `eth_mac` ***is*** a variable. But maybe that's a red herring. What do you mean by "not working"? If you're getting an error, you need to tell us and post the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341) as well as complete code, i.e. the definition of `get_mac_address`.

Comment: Try printing the raw response, to see what it might be (an error message instead of JSON, perhaps).  Are you sure that `"mascineid"` is spelled correctly?

Comment: Start with `print(response.text)` or `print(response.context)` (instead of printing a JSON response). It is likely the result that is sent back is simply not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

the solution:

```
import requests
import json
    
    
eth_mac = get_mac_address()    
data={'machineid': 1, 'mac': eth_mac}
newHeaders = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
        
response = requests.post('.............device.php',
                 data=json.dumps(data),
                 headers=newHeaders)
        
print(response.text)
```

Thank you team for your responds

Comment: This code is not properly indented. Please [edit] to fix it. Same for the question actually

Comment: So what was the actual problem? The `data` was in the wrong format and the response was not JSON? In that case, it seems like you were asking the wrong question. Beware the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832).